# Adding custom library in zend framework 2 (2.3) in layout template

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem. I want to add my custom library when the webapplication starts and i want use it in application layout. I want to create a form (composed by 2 concatenated select with ajax functions) and it must be visible in all parts of the application. when i tried to use my helper custom library, this is the error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SelectSearchList' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\Easyanimal\module\Application\view\layout\layout.phtml on line 118
```

this is the code of vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php:

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Zend\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/',
    'ZendTest\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/tests/',
    'MyHelpLib\\' => $vendorDir . '/MyHelpLib/',
);
```

this is my help library in vendor/MyHelpLib/LoaderSelect.php:

```
  namespace MyHelpLib

class SelectSearchList {

    public $select;

    public function showOpt (){

        return $select = '<option value="">Select...</option>'; 
    }


}
```

and this my layout in application/view/layout

```
<?php
                     use MyHelpLib\LoaderSelect;
                     $Opt = new SelectSearchList();  
                     echo $Opt->showOpt();
                    ?>
```

i tried to add this in Application/module.php but it isn't work again!

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                    'MyHelpLib' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/MyHelpLib',
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
```

thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Create view helper. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.advanced-usage.html#writing-custom-helpers

Index\src\View\Helper\MyHelpLib

```
namespace Index\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class MyHelpLib extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return 'MyHelper'
    }
}
```

Index\config\module.config.php

```
return array(
    ...
    'view_helpers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'MyHelpLib' => '\Index\View\Helper\MyHelpLib'
        )
    )
);
```

layout.phtml

```
echo $this->MyHelpLib();
```